# Conditional rendering inside return in functional component

Tags: reactjs

How to conditionally render an element inside return in functional component.
I don't want to duplicate the NewWindow component two times.

```
  return (
    <NewWindow
      onUnload={props.closeGradeReport}
      features={{ height: 500, width: 2500 }}
      title='Grade Report Chart'
    >
      <div className='grade-report-chart'>
        <div className='grade-report-chart-header'>
          // I want to render Loading.... or p element inside return
          { 
            isLoading ? <div> Loading...</div> : 
          <p> {selectedUser.name} ({selectedCohort})</p>
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    </NewWindow>
```

I know I can return Loading... inside NewWindow but I don't want to duplicate the component.

Comment: on what condition exactly ?

Comment: on isLoading state value

Comment: It looks like correct. I would like to see how IsLoading is happening.

Comment: @HenokTesfaye Can you add your hooks to see what is happening in those?

Comment: @HenokTesfaye is it rendering correctly and you just need to make sure `NewWindow` isn't mounted when it's still loading?

Answer (score -1):

refactor by using Fragment

```
 return (
    <Fragment>
      {isLoading ? (
        <div> Loading...</div>
      ) : (
        <NewWindow
          onUnload={props.closeGradeReport}
          features={{ height: 500, width: 2500 }}
          title="Grade Report Chart"
        >
          <div className="grade-report-chart">
            <div className="grade-report-chart-header">
              <p>
                {selectedUser.name} ({selectedCohort})
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </NewWindow>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
```

Comment: If you use `Fragment` you can as well use the `<>Content</>` syntax right?

Comment: @Trisma You are right but it depends on React version